# Link MS Project to Access

Tags: ms-access, database-projects

I have a large project tracking database used to track PMs, status, help needed, action items, reports etc. I keep the project schedule in a large MS-Project file. I've exhausted all efforts to have my organization invest in an MS-Project server.
How can I use the data found in my project file: Task Name, Resource, Start Date, End Date... etc as source data into my access database. Can these files be linked somehow if I put the project ID# into my project file as a foreign key? I just need to make the data available to people other than the PM. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an [odbc driver for project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.MSProjectODBCDriver)

You could try attaching access directly via a linked table.